# How to multi split column in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following dataframe:

```
A B C     D
0 1 1  x = EUR 50; y= 4
1 2 2  x = EUR 60; y= 5
2 3 3  x = EUR 70; y= 6
```

The D column has both = and ; as delimiter. I want to convert the above data frame to the below one, i.e remove EUR and split the row values in columns, and attach it back to the original dataframe.

```
A B C  x   y
0 1 1  50  4
1 2 2  60  5
2 3 3  70  6
```

I have used `df.iterrows` but it takes forever to run on the dataframe. My dataframe contains 1 million rows.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the numerical values from the column with `extract`. You can make the regular expression more robust (e.g., `'^\s*x\s+=\sEUR\s+(\d+);\s+y=\s+(\d+)\s*$'`) if needed.

```
PATTERN = '(\d+)\D+(\d+)' # Digits - non-digits - digits
df[['x', 'y']] = df['D'].str.extract(PATTERN)
df.drop('D', axis=1, inplace=True)
#   A B C   x  y
#0  0 1 1  50  4
#1  1 2 2  60  5
#2  2 3 3  70  6
```

Comment: I will check your answer today. Maybe an explanation of extract function and what you have written would also be helpful ?

Comment: Hi,
It didnot work since the values in D column are dynamic. As mentioned, the only delimeters are semi colon ';'  and '=' equal sign. It failed on the following line
x = EUR 10; y = 20; z = EUR 30; u = 1; v = 0%

Comment: You should have given a better example.

Comment: Any help DYZ ? Plz

Comment: Anybody caring to help me out here ?